# Getting started with Microservices architecture

Tags: api, rest, authentication, architecture

I'm very new to Microservices, and I would like to model something simple on paper: An application that allows users to login and upload photos (for sake of example).

I assume I would need:

- Login service
- User service
- Pictures service

Can anyone assist with describing what the APIs would look like?

**Login Service:**

- (POST) Login?user=username&pwd=password - *Logs a user in*

**User Service:**

- (GET) User&user_id=123 - *Gets the specified user*
- (POST) User - *Creates new user*
- (POST) User&user_id=123&name=John - *Updates existing user*
- ***How would a delete look like in this example***

Of course, the photos would follow similar suit to the User Service.

However, I'm having a difficult time  understanding how, say, the Login service will be used? Does this mean we have to call the login service *every time* that we need to authenticate a user? Or what would the general interaction be?

Thanks for any insight

Answer (score 0):

For securing APIs the de facto approach is to do something like this:-

**Authentication**
Authenticating a user usually happens once per *session* - where *session* generally refers to a period of time in which the user is automatically logged out if the client is inactive for a specified period.

For example, if using Enterprise Java, you would usually configure your application server to timeout the HttpSession within a certain period of inactivity. You would authenticate the user - usually by comparing basic authentication credentials (username/password) against some profile you stored for them after they registered (using some Registration service). As part of authenticating a user, a HttpSession would be created and the user's ROLE is stored and checked on each request to check if the session is still valid. If the session has timed out, then the user needs to be directed to the authentication service again.

If using a stateless framework (no session hanging around between requests) then you would usually pass some token back and forth for each request and have some sort of validation mechanism ie. user profile stored in cache.

Think of authentication as ONCE PER SESSION.

**Authorization**
For each request (assuming the session is still valid) you would check that the user's ROLE has the necessary privileges to carry out the action requested.

OAuth - an example of an Authorization framework) - is generally designed for authenticating third-party clients to access one of your user's resources but if you have a look at OAuth 2 then it will give you an understanding of the token-based approach at authenticating a user/client between requests.

Think of authorization as EVERY REQUEST.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I've read a bit about the authentication/authorization mechanisms. Would this approach also apply for internal services (i.e. not 3rd party, but services that are part of the main application) to access another internal services' APIs?

Comment: If the Internal service can be accessed by a client/service not under your control and can manipulate (Create/Read/Update/Delete) data that should be protected then yes you need to protect it in some way. The question is how do your internal components access the service? If it is say a request to your domain over a public interface eg. http://yourapp.com/users/list then you need to secure it because it can be used maliciously.